# Animation flickering in java android

Tags: java, android, animation, flicker, doublebuffered

hope someone helps witch flickering. I'm been trying to wrote game based on youtube tutorial by RetroChicken but run into a problem with animation of my player object and background. Only coding 4 days in java, first year studying IT so i'm newbie af. I think its someting with double buffering (as i was reading in other topic but still dont know how to applay it to my code). 
I'm writing in android studio. Here is my animation class and animatorMenager

```
public class AnimationManager {

private Animations[] animationses;
private int animationIndex = 0;

public AnimationManager(Animations[] animationses){
    this.animationses = animationses;
}

public void playAnim(int index){
    for(int i = 0; i < animationses.length; i++){
        if(i == index)
            if(!animationses[index].isPlaying())
            animationses[i].play();
        else
            animationses[i].stop();
    }
    animationIndex = index;
}
public void draw(Canvas canvas, Rect rect){

    if(animationses[animationIndex].isPlaying())
        animationses[animationIndex].draw(canvas,rect);
}
public void update(){
    if(animationses[animationIndex].isPlaying())
        animationses[animationIndex].update();
}
}
```

And Animation

```
public class Animations {

private Bitmap[] frames;
private int frameIndex;

public static boolean isPlaying = false;
public boolean isPlaying(){
    return isPlaying;
}
public void play(){
    isPlaying = true;
    frameIndex = 0;
    lastFrame = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
public void stop(){
    isPlaying = false;
}

private float frameTime;
private long lastFrame;

public Animations(Bitmap[] frames, float animTime){
    this.frames = frames;
    frameIndex = 0;
    frameTime = animTime/frames.length;
    lastFrame = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
public void draw(Canvas canvas, Rect destination){
    if(!isPlaying){
        return;
    }
    //scaleRect(destination);
    canvas.drawBitmap(frames[frameIndex], null, destination, new Paint());
}
/*
private void  scaleRect(Rect rect){
    float whRatio = (float)(frames[frameIndex].getWidth()/frames[frameIndex].getHeight());
    if(rect.width() > rect.height()){
        rect.left = rect.right - (int)(rect.height() * whRatio);
    }else{
        rect.top = rect.bottom - (int)(rect.height() * (1/whRatio));
    }
}
*/

public void update(){
    if(!isPlaying){
        return;
    }
    if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastFrame > frameTime*1000){
        frameIndex++;
        frameIndex = frameIndex >= frames.length ? 0 : frameIndex;
        lastFrame = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
}
```

And maybe Player class will help

```
public class PlayerCar implements GameObject {

private Rect car;
int color;

private Animations idle;
private Animations driveLeft;
private Animations driveRight;
private  AnimationManager animManager;
private int state;


public PlayerCar(Rect car, int color){
    this.car = car;
    this.color = color;

    BitmapFactory bf = new BitmapFactory();
    Bitmap idleImg = bf.decodeResource(Constant.CURRENT_CONTEXT.getResources(), R.drawable.car1_spr);
    Bitmap left = bf.decodeResource(Constant.CURRENT_CONTEXT.getResources(), R.drawable.car1_spr);
    Bitmap right = bf.decodeResource(Constant.CURRENT_CONTEXT.getResources(), R.drawable.car1_spr);

    idle = new Animations(new Bitmap[]{idleImg}, 2);

    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    m.postRotate(-5);
    left = Bitmap.createBitmap(left, 0, 0, left.getWidth(), left.getHeight(),m,false);
    driveLeft = new Animations(new Bitmap[]{left}, 2);
    m.postRotate(10);
    right = Bitmap.createBitmap(right, 0, 0, right.getWidth(), right.getHeight(),m,false);
    driveRight = new Animations(new Bitmap[]{right}, 2);

    animManager = new AnimationManager(new Animations[]{idle, driveRight,driveLeft});

}
public void decrementY(float y){
    car.top -= y;
    car.bottom -= y;
}

public Rect getRectangle() {
    return car;
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    //Paint paint = new Paint();
    //paint.setColor(color);
    //canvas.drawRect(car, paint);
    animManager.draw(canvas,car);
}

@Override
public void update() {
    animManager.update();
}

public void update(Point point){

    //left,top,right,bottom
    car.set(point.x - car.width() / 2, point.y - car.height() / 2, point.x + car.width() / 2, point.y + car.height() / 2);

    if(GameplayScene.carGravity <= -5)
        state = 1;
    else if(GameplayScene.carGravity >= 5)
        state = 2;
    else if (GameplayScene.carGravity == 0)
        state = 0;

    animManager.playAnim(state);
    animManager.update();
}


}
```

**************************UPDATE*******************************

as my reserch go on i found out that in fact i'am using doublebuffer by using bitmap and bitmapfactor in my Player class, so it isn't fault, of not doublebuffering, in fact i think its something witch updating my position in game panel class so i'm adding this class too

```
package com.example.szatan_bies.myapplication;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

import static android.graphics.Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD;
import static com.example.szatan_bies.myapplication.Constant.SCREEN_HEIGHT;
import static com.example.szatan_bies.myapplication.Constant.SCREEN_WIDTH;
import static com.example.szatan_bies.myapplication.Difficulty.DENSITY;
import static 
com.example.szatan_bies.myapplication.Difficulty.HORIZONTAL_SPEED;
import static 
com.example.szatan_bies.myapplication.Difficulty.VERTICAL_SPEED;

/**
 * Created by Szatan - Bies on 08.08.2017.
 */

public class GameplayScene implements Scene {


private PlayerCar player;
private Point playerPoint;
public static double carGravity = 0;
private int isTouch = 1;
private ObstacleManagerCars obstacleManagerCars;
private ObstacleManagerLantern obstacleManagerLantern;
private ObstacleManagerPeople obstacleManagerPeople;
private ManagerBackground background;
public static int score = 0;
public boolean gameOver = false;
private long gameOverTime;

public GameplayScene(){

    player = new PlayerCar(new Rect(100,100,200,300), Color.rgb(255,0,0));
    playerPoint = new Point(SCREEN_WIDTH/2,SCREEN_HEIGHT - 300);
    player.update(playerPoint);
    obstacleManagerCars = new ObstacleManagerCars(2000 + (DENSITY),250,Color.BLACK); //(ObstacleGap,,)
    obstacleManagerLantern = new ObstacleManagerLantern(SCREEN_HEIGHT/2 ,100,Color.BLACK); //(ObstacleGap,,)
    obstacleManagerPeople = new ObstacleManagerPeople(0,15,Color.BLUE);
    background = new ManagerBackground(SCREEN_HEIGHT,Color.GRAY);

}

public void reset(){
    playerPoint = new Point(SCREEN_WIDTH/2,SCREEN_HEIGHT - 300);
    player.update(playerPoint);
    obstacleManagerCars = new ObstacleManagerCars(2000 + (DENSITY),250,Color.BLACK); //(ObstacleGap,,)
    obstacleManagerLantern = new ObstacleManagerLantern(SCREEN_HEIGHT/2 ,100,Color.BLACK); //(ObstacleGap,,)
    obstacleManagerPeople = new ObstacleManagerPeople(0,15,Color.BLUE);
    background = new ManagerBackground(SCREEN_HEIGHT,Color.GRAY);
    carGravity = 0;
    isTouch = 1;
}

@Override
public void terminate() {
    SceneManager.ACTIVE_SCENE = 0;
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

    background.draw(canvas);
    player.draw(canvas);
    obstacleManagerCars.draw(canvas);
    obstacleManagerLantern.draw(canvas);
    obstacleManagerPeople.draw(canvas);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setTypeface(DEFAULT_BOLD);
    paint.setTextSize(60);
    canvas.drawText(""+score, 60, 60, paint);
}
@Override
public void update() {

    if(!gameOver) {
        if (playerPoint.x >= 250 && playerPoint.x <= (SCREEN_WIDTH - 250)) {
            player.update(playerPoint = new Point((int) (playerPoint.x - (carGravity)), playerPoint.y));
        } else if (playerPoint.x <= 250) {
            if (isTouch == 3) {
                carGravity = 0;
            }else if(isTouch == 2) {carGravity = -5 - VERTICAL_SPEED; player.update(playerPoint = new Point(251, playerPoint.y));}
        } else if (playerPoint.x >= SCREEN_WIDTH - 250) {
            if (isTouch == 2) {
                carGravity = 0;
            } else if(isTouch == 3){carGravity = 5 + VERTICAL_SPEED;player.update(playerPoint = new Point(SCREEN_WIDTH - 251, playerPoint.y));}
        }
        score += 13;
        background.update();
        obstacleManagerCars.update();
        obstacleManagerLantern.update();
        obstacleManagerPeople.update();


        // COLLISIONS //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        if(obstacleManagerCars.playerCollideCars(player) == 1){
            gameOver = true;
            gameOverTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            score = 0;
        }
        if(obstacleManagerPeople.playerCollidePeople(player) == 0 || obstacleManagerPeople.playerCollidePeople(player) == 1){
        }


        if(isTouch == 2){
            carGravity = -5 - VERTICAL_SPEED;
        }else if(isTouch == 3){
            carGravity = 5 + VERTICAL_SPEED;
        }

        if(obstacleManagerCars.playerCollideCars(player) == 2 && isTouch == 3){carGravity = 5 + VERTICAL_SPEED;}
        else if(obstacleManagerCars.playerCollideCars(player) == 3 && isTouch == 2){carGravity = -5 - VERTICAL_SPEED;}
        else if (obstacleManagerCars.playerCollideCars(player) == 2 || obstacleManagerCars.playerCollideCars(player) == 3){
            player.update(playerPoint = new Point(playerPoint.x, playerPoint.y));
            carGravity = 0;
        }

        if(obstacleManagerLantern.playerCollideLantern(player)){
            player.update(playerPoint = new Point(playerPoint.x , playerPoint.y + 15));
        }
        // DIFFICULTY AND SCORE ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        if(score < 0 || player.getRectangle().top >= SCREEN_HEIGHT) {
            gameOver = true;
            gameOverTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            score = 0;
        }
        if(score < 5000) {
            VERTICAL_SPEED = 0;
            HORIZONTAL_SPEED = 0;
            DENSITY = 0;
        }else if(score > 5000 && score < 10000){
            VERTICAL_SPEED = 0;
            HORIZONTAL_SPEED = -3000.0f;
            DENSITY = -1000;
        }else if(score > 10000 && score < 50000){
            VERTICAL_SPEED = 1;
            HORIZONTAL_SPEED = -5000.0f;
            DENSITY = -3000;
        }else if(score > 50000 && score < 70000){
            VERTICAL_SPEED = 2;
            HORIZONTAL_SPEED = -7000.0f;
            DENSITY = -3500;
        }else if(score > 80000){
            VERTICAL_SPEED = 2;
            HORIZONTAL_SPEED = -8500.0f;
            DENSITY = -4000;
        }
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }

}

@Override
public void reciveTouch(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        if(gameOver && System.currentTimeMillis() - gameOverTime >= 2000){
            gameOver = false;
            gameOverTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            reset();
        }
    }
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        isTouch = 2;
    } else {
        isTouch = 3;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to double buffer. You must draw to a separate buffered image first. You must change `animManager.draw` so it accepts a `BufferedImage` rather than a `Canvas`

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB)
    animManager.draw(img, car);
    Graphics g = canvas.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(0, 0, null);
}
```

Comment: but there is problem with that because BuferredImage and graphics is not included in AndroidSDK witch i'm using, sorry I should mention it earlier